# Bookmark file can't be saved in Emacs

Tags: emacs, bookmarks

I use Emacs GNU Emacs 26.2 (build 1, x86_64-w64-mingw32). When I try to save bookmarks, I get the message:

```
bookmark-write-file: Invalid bookmark-file
```

Even if I start Emacs with an empty .emacs file, I get the same message.
I have full acess as user to the file.
Any idea what is going wrong?
Cheers
Renger

Answer (score 0):

**Initial reply (before update - see below)**

I thought your bookmark file was corrupted.

Note that even if you start Emacs with no init file (e.g. `emacs -Q`) it will pick up your bookmark file if it is stored in the expected location.

You can move your bookmark file elsewhere temporarily, to test. You can then edit it (e.g. examine it), to find the problem. You can bisect it recursively by commenting out 1/2, then 3/4, 7/8, etc. to find any particular part(s) that are problematic. Delete or repair those parts.

---

**UPDATED -**

Based on your description and comments, I'm guessing that you're using [Bookmark+](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BookmarkPlus), and that you stumbled on a bug when *using an empty bookmark file*.

I just uploaded a fix for a bug that I think might address the problem you ran into. Please download and try the latest version of file [`bookmark+-bmu.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/bookmark%2b-bmu.el).

Sorry for the trouble. If you still have the problem, and you're using Bookmark+, follow up with `M-x customize-group bookmark-plus` - click the link **Send Bug Report** near the top.

Comment: Hi Drew, I deleted all bookmark files, restarted Emacs and now have an empty file with the following in it: 

Bookmark file:
~/.emacs.d/bookmarks

All Bookmarks
-------------

If I try to save this empty bookmark file with "bookmark-save" I once again get the same error message.

Comment: If that's the content of your "empty" bookmark file then it's not a bookmark file. Just remove it, and start over (create a bookmark, try to save the (new) bookmark file with that bookmark. What you describe doesn't sound like the content of a bookmark file; it sounds like what you see when you try to list your bookmarks (e.g. `C-x r l`, aka `bookmark-bmenu-list`).

Comment: Here is the bookmark file:

;;;; Emacs Bookmark Format Version 1 ;;;; -*- coding: utf-8-emacs -*- 
;;; This format is meant to be slightly human-readable;
;;; nevertheless, you probably don't want to edit it.
;;; -*- End Of Bookmark File Format Version Stamp -*-
nil